# How clone source repository in /tmp/ space of cloud function

Tags: python, git, github, version-control, google-cloud-functions

I want clone source repository into /tmp/ space of cloud function.I have explored the subprocess module.But No success.I have also explored gitpython.But how to clone repo in git python.See  below code.But it is not working in cloud function.But when am running this code locally it is working fine.In cloud function function it giving error like:fatal: could not read Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com'

```
def clone_gitpython():
    import git
    #path = 'C:\\Users\\anuragja\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp\\'
    path='/tmp/'
    try:
        git.Git(path).clone("https://source.developers.google.com/p/dev-sandbox-2XXXX/r/poc_git")
        for x in os.listdir("/tmp"):
            print(" cloned files name")
            print(x)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Update
Now I Updated code by adding ssh key on source repo and running git ssh command for cloning but still unable to cloned.Getting Error "ssh: connect to host source.developers.google.com port 2022: Connection timed out
"

```
def hello_world(event=None, context=None):
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    print(dir_path)
    print("cloning into tmp")
    url = "ssh://jainXXX1XXX@gmail.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/dev-sandbox-XXXX/r/test_repo"
    path_temp = '/tmp'
    try:
        git.Repo.clone_from(url, path_temp , env={"GIT_SSH_COMMAND": 'ssh -i' + dir_path + '/id_rsa.pub '})
        print("cloning completed 200")
        for x in os.listdir("/tmp"):
            print("List of files")
            print(x)
    except  Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Comment: Does this code work locally? What do you mean by *it is not working*? Please clarify by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): why do you need to clone a git repo in your Cloud Function?

Comment: @DustinIngram:The idea is to clone sourcerepo branch where multiple sql queries are there which  needs to run on bigquery.Cloud composer option is costly.Exploring Cloudfunction for running sql queries from clonning into /tmp.OR I am into XY problem dilemma

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clone my repo on local machine with this code. On cloud function I got connection time up

```
def hello_world(request):

  from google.cloud import storage
  from git import Repo
  import os 
  storage_client = storage.Client()

  path_temp = '/tmp'
  path_clone = path_temp + '/clone'
  try:
    os.mkdir(path_clone)
  except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory failed")
  else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory ")

  url = 'ssh://v@.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/user/r/myrepo'




  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('source-marian')
  blob = bucket.blob('id_rsa')
  envFile = path_temp + '/id_rsa'
  print ("Successfully reading rsa ")


  blob.download_to_filename(envFile)

  print ("Download the file from bucket")
  with open (envFile, 'r') as f :
    print(f.read())

  ssh_cmd ='ssh -i '+ envFile

  print(ssh_cmd)
  print (url)
  print (path_clone)
  print(env)


  try:
    print("start git clone")
    git.Repo.clone_from(url, path_clone , branch='master', env={'GIT_SSH_COMMAND': ssh_cmd})
    print ("end git clone")
    print("cloning completed 200")
    for x in os.listdir(path_clone):
        print("List of files")
        print(x)
  except  Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

And added a requirements.txt which has:

```
  gitpython
  google-cloud-storage
```

Comment: HI When I am trying to clone Source repo I am getting error: "ssh: connect to host source.developers.google.com port 2022: Connection timed out
" .Is there any way to open a connection for source repository from cloud function.

Comment: I oreder to clone using ssh you need to authenticate with ssh on local machine [link](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#ssh)

Comment: How can I register private ssh key with cloud function?

Comment: This is what I can not figure out. I tried to create the ssh keys on local machine, register the public, copy the private on cloud function from cloud storage and run the clone command. I still get connection time out. If I run the code locally it works.

Comment: Same in my case. Runnig on local but not on cloud function